# javascript firefox throws operation is insecure error

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I'm trying to resize an uploaded image, set it back to the input element before submitting.

```
  $("#upload_button").click(function(){
            var imgToUpload = document.getElementById('id_picture').files;
            for (var x = 0; x < imgToUpload.length; x ++){
                var getImg = imgToUpload[x];
                console.log(typeof getImg);
                if (! imgToUpload[x].type.match(/image.*/)){
                    alert("not an image");
                    return false;
                }

                var img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(getImg);

                var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width  = 20;
                canvas.height = 20; 
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 20, 20);

                var resizedUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7);
                var byteString = atob(resizedUrl.split(",")[1]);

                var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
                for (var index = 0; index < byteString.length; index++){
                    ia[index] = byteString.charCodeAt(index);
                }

                var bob =  new Blob([ab], {"type": getImg.type});

                var p = document.getElementById('id_picture');
                p.value = bob;

                $("#upload_form").submit();

            }
        });
```

when i reach the `p.value = bob`, i will encounter the mentioned problem. Am i doing it wrong?

(i read that i can simply use `canvas.toDataURL` and set it to another hidden input, but I'm trying to see if this is possible)

Comment: Are you running the page from a server or from a `file:///` URI?  A lot of operations are blocked if you load the page from the local filesystem.

Comment: Robertc I am serving the page locally from a django server

Answer (score 0):

You can use toDataURL

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("ex1");
var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Client example:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html

Server(PHP) example http://html5stars.com/?p=99

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What's that?